# Real Schur form and upper hessenberg form

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am a bit confused, why can upper hessenberg form guarantee the convergence, but not the real schur form? They have similar forms and their eigenvalues lies on their diagonals, or 2 x 2 blocks in the diagonal. thanks!

Btw, why is this matrix in upper hessenberg form? 
$$
A' =
\left[
\begin{array}{rccr}
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$
A matrix of the form
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 x & x & x & x & x \\
 x & x & x & x & x \\
 0 & x & x & x & x \\
 0 & 0 & x & x & x \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & x & x \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$
with $x$ any number in $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 3):

The upper Hessenberg form allows for nonzero entries on the first subdiagonal, but no more. The diagonal and first subdiagonal are colored in $\color{blue}{blue}.$

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
 \color{blue}{0} & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 \color{blue}{-1} & \color{blue}{0} & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \color{blue}{0} & \color{blue}{0} & -1 \\
 0 & 0 & \color{blue}{1} & \color{blue}{0} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
The eigenvalue spectrum for this matrix is
$$
\lambda \left( \mathbf{A} \right) = \left\{ 
i, i, -i, -i
\right\}
$$
The ratio of eigenvalues is
$$
\Big\vert \frac{\lambda_{1}}{\lambda_{2}} \Big\rvert = 1.
$$
This is why this matrix will not converge.

Comment: I've attached another picture in the question. That is the definition in our textbook, how to associate the matrix with that?

Comment: @J.doe: In the figure, blank (empty entries) must be $0$. The $x$ entries can have any number, including $0$.

Comment: So as long as the lower left submatrix is 0, the rest of the entries can be any value. Is that correct?

Comment: @J.doe: Yes. The sample matrix in your example was updated.

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you know what is the difference between real schur form and upper hessenberg form when used to find eigenvalues?